# Struts 2 - Date instance become String

Tags: forms, hibernate, struts2, submit, action

When I submit the form, input error is occur. `JourneyDate` is instance of 'Date'. But ,here it become String which is not accepted by the setter and getter.

```
<s:hidden name="JourneyDate" value="%{JourneyDate}"></s:hidden>
```

I want `JourneyPlan` as Date Type, but it become String.

Comment: will you some your codes, its not possible to visualize the scenario or what problem you are facing.

Comment: What values do you want to get and which of them is required?

Comment: Take a look at Struts2 type conversion: http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/type-conversion.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try intercepting the value before passing it to the getter/setter. For example send JourneyDateString from your form, create a Date from the String, and then pass that to your getter/setter. Something like:

```
public void setJourneyDateString(String journeyDateString)
{
     //journeyDateString could be "2013-03-28" for example
     Date journeyDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(journeyDateString);
     setJourneyDate(journeyDate);
}
```

Comment: There are better ways to do this in Struts2 and in general also.

Answer (score 0):

The object that you've set in the `value` attribute will keep it's type as `Date`. Then you need to define corresponding setter in the action to set the value of the `Date`. It will convert to string if you place the value in the body of the tag.